# Div with no text is aligning differently compared to Div with text

Tags: html, css

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tffs1tw4/1/) of the below:

```css
.filterDivActual, #filterSeparator {
  display: inline-block;
}
.filterDivActual {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: grey;
  position: relative;
}
#filterSeparator {
  height: 50px;
  width: 5px; 
  background-color: black; 
}
```

```html
<div id='filterDiv'>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>Top</div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>New</div> 
  <div id='filterSeparator'></div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>Today</div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>Yesterday</div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>None</div>
</div>
```

What I want is for the `#filterSeparator` to be aligned with the other `div`s.

For some reason, all the other `div`s are below the `#filterSeparator`.

If I put text inside `#filterSeparator`, then it works.

Is there a way for me to get it to work without placing any text inside `#filterSeparator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/tffs1tw4/3/)

For **inline** / **inline-block** elements, use the `vertical-align` property:

```
.filterDivActual, #filterSeperator {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle ; /* or some other value: */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it does this but you can fix it by using float:left; instead of display:inline-block

Comment: ...than if you want to use for the parent: `text-align: center;` (to center align the inner `inline/inline-block` children) you'll be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#filterSeparator:before {
   content: ".";
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```css
.filterDivActual, #filterSeparator {
  display: inline-block;
}
.filterDivActual {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
 
  color: grey;
  position: relative;
}
#filterSeparator {
  height: 50px;
  width: 5px; 
  background-color: black; 
   
}
#filterSeparator:before {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='filterDiv'>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>Top</div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>New</div> 
  <div id='filterSeparator'></div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>Today</div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>Yesterday</div>
  <div class='filterDivActual'>None</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note your solution also needs `line-height: 50px` (same as `height`), which isn't included in OP's code, but is in his fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Putting content in the empty `<div>` will fix it.

```
<div id='filterSeperator'>&nbsp;</div>
```